# Using rbind to merge data frames

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames A and B of dimensions 2 x 5 like this:

```
 A = data.frame(GeneA1=-0.02:1.89, GeneB2=0.25:1.99, GeneB3=0.17:1.87, GeneB4=0.3:1.63, GeneC2=0.29:1.97, row.names=c("sample 1", "sample 2"))

 B = data.frame(GeneA1=0.52:-0.04, GeneB1=1.1:0.08, GeneB3=0.72:0.03, GeneB5=0.78:0.06, GeneC2=0.78:0.25, row.names=c("sample 1", "sample 2"))
```

For both A & B, the rows are samples and the columns are gene type

I want to try and merge A & B using `rbind`, adding `NA`s where the gene types don't match up. I've heard there's a way to do this, using the `setdiff` argument but I don't know how?

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible example data?

Comment: What do you mean by 'reproducible'? The example data I've provided illustrates my problem?

Comment: Please use R syntax in your code. What you show might be Matlab code?

Comment: FYI info on posting on SO and reproducible examples can be seen here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).   Have you looked at merge()

Comment: Sorry! I've edited my post so it now has R code

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029743/r-merge-or-combine-by-rownames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `merge`:

```
A=data.frame(A1=c(-0.02,1.89),B2=c(0.25,1.99),B3=c(0.17,1.87),B4=c(0.3,1.63),C2=c(0.29,1.97))
B=data.frame(A1=c(0.52,-0.04),B1=c(1.1,0.08),B3=c(0.72,0.03),B5=c(0.78,0.06),C2=c(0.78,0.25))
C<-merge(A, B, all=T)
View(C)
```

Comment: See my comment to Jilber's answer.

Comment: @Marie-Anne Frenken what's the difference between your answer and mine?? Is it just a duplicated answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge`

```
> AB <- merge(A, B, all=TRUE)
> AB[,order(names(AB))]  # to get the result ordered by colnames 
  Gene A1 Gene B1 Gene B2 Gene B3 Gene B4 Gene B5 Gene C2
1   -0.04    0.08      NA    0.03      NA    0.06    0.25
2   -0.02      NA    0.25    0.17    0.30      NA    0.29
3    0.52    1.10      NA    0.72      NA    0.78    0.78
4    1.89      NA    1.99    1.87    1.63      NA    1.97
```

Where `A` and `B` are as follows:

```
A <- matrix(c(-0.02, 0.25, 0.17, 0.3, 0.29, 
              1.89, 1.99, 1.87, 1.63, 1.97), 
            nrow=2, byrow=TRUE,
            dimnames=list(NULL, c("Gene A1", "Gene B2", 
                                  "Gene B3", 
                                  "Gene B4", "Gene C2")))

B <- matrix(c(0.52, 1.1, 0.72, 0.78, 0.78, 
              -0.04, 0.08, 0.03, 0.06,0.25), 
            nrow=2, byrow=TRUE,
            dimnames=list(NULL, c("Gene A1", "Gene B1",
                                  "Gene B3", 
                                  "Gene B5", "Gene C2")))
```

Comment: I've tried using merge but when I do this on bigger data frames, I often run into the error message: "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names"

So I was wondering if there was a way to do this using rbind?

Comment: @Jilber "By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they both have". So if both dataframes have the same values on shared columns, they will get merged? Add `1.89, 999, 1.87, 999, 1.97` rows to both `A` and `B`, to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# dummy data
A <- read.table(text="
Gene A1, Gene B2, Gene B3, Gene B4, Gene C2
0.52, 0.25, 0.17, 0.3, 0.29
1.89, 1.99, 1.87, 1.63, 1.97",
                sep=",", header=TRUE)
B <- read.table(text="
Gene A1, Gene B1, Gene B3, Gene B5, Gene C2
0.52, 1.1, 0.72, 0.78, 0.78
-0.04, 0.08, 0.03, 0.06,0.25",
                sep=",", header=TRUE)

#transpose and merge
tAB <- merge(t(A),t(B),by="row.names",all=TRUE)

#keep gene names
col <- tAB[,1]

#exclude rownames, transpose
output <- t(tAB[,-1])

#update colnames
colnames(output) <- col

#output
#     Gene.A1 Gene.B1 Gene.B2 Gene.B3 Gene.B4 Gene.B5 Gene.C2
#V1.x   -0.02      NA    0.25    0.17    0.30      NA    0.29
#V2.x    1.89      NA    1.99    1.87    1.63      NA    1.97
#V1.y    0.52    1.10      NA    0.72      NA    0.78    0.78
#V2.y   -0.04    0.08      NA    0.03      NA    0.06    0.25
```