# How do I turn the rows of my data.frame into columns?

Tags: r

I have a series of variable-specific data.frames like the following:

Variable 1:

```
LOCATION 2014.01  2014.02  2014.03  2014.04
902010   7        -3       14       5
```

Variable 2:

```
LOCATION 2014.01  2014.02  2014.03  2014.04
902010   9        11       6        3
```

I'd like to transform transform and combine them into the following format.

```
LOCATION    DATE     VARIABLE1  VARIABLE2
902010      2014.01  7          9
902010      2014.02  -3         11
902010      2014.03  14         6
902010      2014.04  5          3
```

I think the right approach is to transform one data.frame then add data from the others where date and location match.

The answers to similar-sounding questions recommend the library reshape2 or the function t(), but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use them for this scenario. I've also seen recommendations for the time-series library zoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. reshape your data in the long format using `melt`
2. combine the data.frames by (LOCATION and dates) using `merge`

Here a complete solution:
    library(reshape2)

```
dat1 <- 'LOCATION 2014.01  2014.02  2014.03  2014.04
902010   7        -3       14       5'

dat2 <- 'LOCATION 2014.01  2014.02  2014.03  2014.04
902010   9        11       6        3'

ll <- lapply(list(dat1,dat2),function(x){
dat <- read.table(text=x,header=TRUE)
melt(dat,id.vars ='LOCATION')
})

res <- merge(ll[[1]],ll[[2]],by=1:2)

# LOCATION variable value.x value.y
# 1   902010 X2014.01       7       9
# 2   902010 X2014.02      -3      11
# 3   902010 X2014.03      14       6
# 4   902010 X2014.04       5       3
```

An extra step is to coerce you variable column to a valid date.

```
res$variable <- 
as.Date(paste0(sub('X','',res$variable),'.01'),
        format='%Y.%m.%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Define a `merge` function, `merge12` which merges by the first two variables and a `melt` function, `melt1`, which uses the first variable as the id.  Then define `L`, a list of data frames, and run `Reduce` like this:

```
library(reshape2)

merge12 <- function(..., by = 1:2) merge(..., by = by)
melt1 <- function(..., id = 1) melt(..., id = id)

L <- list(DF1, DF2)
Reduce(merge12, lapply(L, melt1))
```

For the data frames in the question this gives the following

```
  LOCATION variable value.x value.y
1   902010  2014.01       7       9
2   902010  2014.02      -3      11
3   902010  2014.03      14       6
4   902010  2014.04       5       3
```

**Note:** This works for more than two data frames as well. Just put them all in the list `L`.

**2) fn$**  Using `fn$` in gsubfn which allows function arguments to be expressed as formulas we can write the above in more compact way:

```
library(reshape2)
library(gsubfn)

L <- list(DF1, DF2)
fn$Reduce(~ merge(..., by = 1:2), fn$lapply(L, ~ melt(..., id = 1)))
```

giving the same result.

**ADDED** (2)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried merge() function?

You might also find it useful!
[Merge or combine by rownames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029743/r-merge-or-combine-by-rownames)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get there using base R functions.

```
> cb <- cbind(var1[1], names(var1)[-1], sapply(list(var1[-1], var2[-1]), t))
> names(cb)[2:4] <- c("DATE", "VAR1", "VAR2") 
> cb
#   LOCATION     DATE VAR1 VAR2
# 1   902010 X2014.01    7    9
# 2   902010 X2014.02   -3   11
# 3   902010 X2014.03   14    6
# 4   902010 X2014.04    5    3
```

And if you don't mind the columns being in a different order, it can be shortened to three columns,

```
> rb <- rbind(var1 = var1, var2 = var2)
> cbind(t(rb[-1]), LOC = var1$LOCATION)
#          var1 var2    LOC
# X2014.01    7    9 902010
# X2014.02   -3   11 902010
# X2014.03   14    6 902010
# X2014.04    5    3 902010
```