# Merge by rownames in data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table, r-rownames

I wanted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029743/merge-or-combine-by-rownames) solution, two merge two data.tables by row name. It does however not work.

```
z <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,"RND1","WDR", "PLAC8","TYBSA","GRA","TAF"), nrow=6,
    dimnames=list(c("ILMN_1651838","ILMN_1652371","ILMN_1652464","ILMN_1652952","ILMN_1653026","ILMN_1653103"),c("A","B","C","D","symbol")))

tt <-matrix(c("GO:0002009", 8, 342, 1, 0.07, 0.679, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
        "GO:0030334", 6, 343, 1, 0.07, 0.065, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        "GO:0015674", 7, 350, 1, 0.07, 0.065, 1, 0, 0, 0), nrow=10, dimnames= list(c("GO.ID","LEVEL","Annotated","Significant","Expected","resultFisher","ILMN_1652464","ILMN_1651838","ILMN_1711311","ILMN_1653026")))

z <- as.data.frame(z)
tt <- as.data.frame(tt)

setDT(z)
setDT(tt)

merge(tt,z["symbol"],by="row.names",all.x=TRUE)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(z, "symbol") : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

How would this work in data.table?

Comment: `data.table` doesn't support row names (check `z` after `setDT`) so you'll need to add a column to use as the key)

Comment: Your code works if you remove the two `setDT` calls. (I just learned that `base::merge` supports merging by row names.)

Comment: Having said that, I have found the reliance on row names in a frame to be fragile: many (popular) R functions/packages (including `data.table` and `dplyr`) ignore or actively remove row names, so reliance on them is a risky venture. Because of this, the recommendation is almost always "convert to a proper column".

Comment: As suggested move rownames to columns, then merge. Or keep matrix as matrix and merge based on *match*: [see another answer from your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029852/680068)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I forgot that data.table does not support row names. I don't normally use them, not entirely sure anymore why I wanted to now.

Comment: I remember now why I wanted to use row names. I used `rowSums`, which worked nicely on a data.frame with row names, but not so much on the data.table with a character column.

Answer (score 0):

You can just merge two matrices with `merge` and the merged set will be a `data.frame` with the column name "Row.names". After that you can if desired make it a data.table.

```
merged <- merge(tt, z, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)

setDT(merged)
```

Or you can decide to convert the matrices to a data.table first and add the dimnames as a new column. Then merge those two data.tables.

```
merge(
  as.data.table(z)[, id := dimnames(z)[[1]]],
  as.data.table(tt)[, id := dimnames(tt)[[1]]],
  all = T
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Merijn, but the point was that I wanted to do it in data.table (which I should have maybe explained better).

Comment: my answer uses data.table...

Comment: Besides that, I also always use data.table by preference. But if in your case you show matrices as starting point (if it were data.tables you would not have row names in the first place) you take the most efficient way to prepare your data. I gave both solutions, either merge as matrices and then convert it to a data.table. Or make them a data.table first and merge them. Being a data.table or not is in that step totally irrelevant.